# How to add a html link tag to a page which uses a layout shared across an application from sitecore

Tags: html, asp.net, sitecore

I have an application built on ASP.net and Sitecore.The application uses a common layout(.aspx file) from sitecore.

Now I have to add a link tag() under head section to a single page.To achieve this,I have to edit common layout but the link tag should appear only on the page I want and not on other pages.How can I achieve this?

I got the below code to add to my common layout.aspx but it is not working and I don't understand what it does.

```
    <% string currentURL = Request.RawUrl;
       if (currentURL == "/") {%>
        <link rel="xxx" href="yyy" />
    <% } %>
```

why we use <% %>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Add a placeholder to your Sitecore layout (.aspx page).
2. Create a sublayout that contains the "link" html.
3. Add the sublayout - created in step 2 - to the specific page(s) you want the link to appear on. Make sure that the sublayout is added to the placeholder you created in step 1.